# What is the best practice to store users on mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm storing job profiles in my db kinda like Linkedin does.
you can sign up as a candidate or as a company but now i have only one table

```
user_tb
```

where `user_tb.user_type` is the tag to identify a candidate user vs a member/visitor, vs. a company

Imagine if i wanted the users to be able to add their own employees of that company.

where the employees should be stored? I'd store them in the main `user_tb` right?
so what about companies? and if i store employees in the same `user_tb` their email cannot be empty... how can i fill emails if i don't have them?

shoudl be user_tb  a separate table from employees?

Comment: Whats the difference between employers and users?

Comment: Does the email _have_ to be a required field?  If so, where are you getting your data?  If the users are filling out a registration form, make the email  address required there.

Comment: i know my question is kind ageneric, but now i have a better understading thanks to you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a separate table for companies and users, and then have a column on the users table for their company id to link them together.  It gets too messy when you try to cram everything together into one table.

If the users table requires an email, and you're wanting a place for companies to add employees, you can require them to give the employees email, or create a separate table for employees that doesn't require an email, but can be checked before signing up a new user to see if they already exist in the "employees" table.

Comment: The question provides too little information on the nature of employee and company relations. A single column might be not enough if we want to express employee's employment history and/or belonging to multiple companies at the same time.

Comment: @Andrea, thanks. I think it validates my thinking. and I think i need to add th eeployee email anyway